# Tab Bar disappear when changin Segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue, tabbar

In a tab I want to check if the user loggedin or not. If the user is logged in I want to show the Account view, if user not loggedin I want to show the Loginview. with this code it works but the table bar disappear. How can I fix that or is there a better way to do that ?

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if let email = userDefaults.valueForKey("token") {  //User logged in
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("AccountSegue", sender: self)
            print("Logged In")
        }
        else {      //User not logged in
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSegue", sender: self)
            print("Not Logged In")
        }


    }
```

Comment: Are you checking if the user is logged in when the app is first opened?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem recently, and you have to use "Unwind Segue's" to not allow the Tab Bar Controller to disappear. But, I have heard that some other people only had to uncheck the "Hide Tab Bar" option in the Attributes Inspector of their Storyboard file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `UITabBarController`, you need to do like this

```
self.selectedIndex = 2
```

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer. When moving between a UITabController's ViewControllers you are not segueing between them, but simply saying which one you'd want to see. So when you perform a segue you push a new ViewController on top of your UITabBarViewController. So the TabBar is not actually disappearing. All you have to do is set the selectedIndex, as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of segue did you declare on the Storyboard? If the TabBar disappears probably you're opening the LoginVC as a modal instead of pushing the view into the active tab NavigationController.

Anyway, why would you let the user navigate through the tabs if it's not logged in yet? Please explain your case better so we'll suggest you a better approach.

Comment: It's a show Segue. 
In the first tab there is some news, user don't have to be logged in to see it.In the second tab user can login and access his account.

Comment: Have you tried pushing the ViewControllers manually instead of using segues? (and of course removing that dispatcher view)